# Hyperlinks with dark blue color (as opposed to regular blue)?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, color

I want my hyperlinks to be a dark blue color. But there is no such option it seems with `\hypersetup`. Or is there?

```
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=DARKBLUE,     
    urlcolor=DARKBLUE,
    }
```

Comment: you should define the color first, check the documentation of color or xcolor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you load the [xcolor](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/xcolor) package with the `svgnames` option (see pp. 42-43 of the package's user guide), the following named colors may suit your needs:

- DarkBlue
- MidnightBlue
- NavyBlue (synonym: Navy)

The package's `x11names` option provides some additional named colors that may be of interest to you:

- Blue4
- DodgerBlue4
- RoyalBlue4
- SlateBlue4

Speaking from personal experience, both `MidnightBlue` and `NavyBlue` are extremely dark; for some (especially older...) readers' eyes, these two colors may not be easy to distinguish from black. Either `Blue4` or `RoyalBlue4` may actually "work" better in practice.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames,x11names,table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.5}
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{1.2pt}\arrayrulecolor{white}
\begin{tabular}{p{0.5in}>{\bfseries}l}
\cellcolor{blue}         & \color{blue}blue (for reference) \\ \hline
\cellcolor{DarkBlue}     & \color{DarkBlue}DarkBlue \\ \hline
\cellcolor{MidnightBlue} & \color{MidnightBlue}MidnightBlue \\ \hline
\cellcolor{NavyBlue}     & \color{NavyBlue}NavyBlue (aka Navy) \\ \hline
\cellcolor{Blue4} & \color{Blue4}Blue4 \\ \hline
\cellcolor{DodgerBlue4} & \color{DodgerBlue4}DodgerBlue4 \\ \hline
\cellcolor{RoyalBlue4} & \color{RoyalBlue4}RoyalBlue4 \\ \hline
\cellcolor{SlateBlue4} & \color{SlateBlue4}SlateBlue4 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE. ahaahhahaah :-)